# ¿Qué quiere decir la segunda columna en las ligas de reputación?

Tags: soporte, reputación

En la reputación semanal pueden visualizarse 4 columnas de puntuaciones, ¿qué quiere decir la segunda columna?

He podido observar que a veces la es una puntuación positiva, otras negativa y otras veces figura no clasificado previamente.

Estos son [mis datos ahora mismo](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/637/week/es-stackoverflow/2020-05-31/96682#96682):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Es el cambio de posiciones de la semana pasada a esta. Es decir, si la semana pasada estabas en el puesto 10 y esta estás en el puesto 7, en esa columna aparecería un +3. Si la semana siguiente vuelves a pasar al puesto 10, verás un -3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se refiere a que si la semana / mes / año / total actual estás en una posición, qué diferencia hay respecto a la franja anterior. Si no hay datos es porque en la franja anterior no tuviste cambio en la reputación, luego no te "clasificaste".

Ejemplo práctico conmigo esta semana respecto la anterior

[Semana 31 mayo a 6 junio](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/637/week/es-stackoverflow/2020-06-01) aparezco como el 33.º y dice que mi cambio es "-1":

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto es porque en la [semana 24 a 30 de mayo](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/637/week/es-stackoverflow/2020-05-24) acabé 32.º:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por tanto, al pasar de 32.º a 33.º el cambio es "-1".

Comment: Perfectamente explicado :)